# Question about Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute $\int_C \frac{cosz}{z(z^2+8)}dz$ by using Cauchy's integral formula along C which is x=+1,-1 and y=+1,-1.

Approach: I know how to use the formula, but I am having problems with the algebra. How do you get in the denominator something like $expression/z-c$?

Comment: Please learn to write fractions properly. Use `\frac{abc}{123(x-c)}` to show $\frac{abc}{123(x-c)}$.

Comment: Use partial fractions to get the integrand as $\cos z$ times a sum of three rational functions.

Comment: @Semiclassical How do you compute partial fractions on complex numbers? For example a different problem $\frac{1}{z^2+4}= \frac{1}{(z-2i)(z+2i)}= \frac{A}{z-2i}+ \frac{B}{z+2i}$

Comment: It's exactly the same as with real numbers (i.e. multiply both sides by the common denominator and match coefficients). There's really nothing different about complex numbers in that respect.